# Android Studio отображает подсказки не для всех значений манифеста

Tags: android-studio

Поправьте, если не совсем корректно озаглавил вопрос. Заметил, часть `uses-permission` и `action` например

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG"/>
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```

не отображаются в подсказках при наборе в Android Studio (как в v1.5.1 так и v2). Интуитивно понимаю, что должно быть например `SMS_RECEIVED` или `permission.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG"`, но приходится корректные значения искать в интернете. Возможно есть какая-то настройка?

Comment: обновитесь до версии 2, хотя у меня работало и в 1.5. А например `uses-permission ... INTERNET` показывает?

Comment: в v1.5.1 uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET показывает.
в v2  action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" не показывает

Comment: Я так почитал, никто не использует `action SMS_RECEIVED`. Достаточно просто добавить `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">`

Comment: а это именно в документации от google, т.е. есть где-то зафиксированный список "обязательный - необязательных" параметров?

Comment: @x55xx, Может вы какой-нибудь старый `android sdk` используете?

Comment: в v1.5.1 Settings>Android SDK>SDK Platform - установлены 4.0.3, 4.2.2, 6.0.   v2 дома, пока проверить не могу, вечером гляну.

Comment: Я на сайте `google.android` по запросу чтение смс нашел статью только с `android 4.4.2 KITKAT`